# Manipulating elements in Java HashSet

Tags: java, loops, hashset

I've searched for a long time for this in here and other places, and could not find my answer:

As part of a project I require to make a set of `Connection` objects (SQL Server) to take and restore connections to (Connection pool).

My issue is how to manipulate the objects in the set:
When a client requests a `Connection` I can remove it from the set, and when he's finished - add it back (since it's all unique values anyway).

But I am having trouble with this.

edit:

My code runs to an issue:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-10" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1597)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:1620)
    at connectionUtilities.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:105)
    at main.Main$1.run(Main.java:22)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

at line:

```java
connection = (Connection)iterator.next();
```

I firstly use a constructor to add 10 connections to the set:

```java
public ConnectionPool() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        try {
            Class.forName(jdbcDriver);
            System.out.println("driver loaded succesfully");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
            connectionSet.add(connection);

            System.out.println("connection created succesfully.");
            System.out.println("Connection id: " + connectionSet.iterator());
            System.out.println("connections Final size= " + connectionSet.size());
            this.counter++;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(connectionSet);
    // String[] conPoolArray = connectionSet.toArray(new
    // String[connectionSet.size()]);
}
```

Here is my `getConnection` method (iterator is declared in the class as):

```java
Iterator iterator = connectionSet.iterator();
```

---

```
public Connection getConnection() {
    synchronized (instance) {
        if (!connectionSet.isEmpty()) {
            connection = (Connection)iterator.next();
            return connection;
        } else {
            try {
                instance.wait();
                instance.getConnection();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return connection;
}
```

I am receiving the `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` error and I understand it's because I can't adjust the set while iterating over it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks up front!

Comment: There's some code missing here... Where are you modifying this set?

Comment: Yea.  You have only explained part of the problem and shown us part of the code.  Obviously (!) you can't modify a `HashSet` or `TreeSet` while iterating it, but why do you need to?  If we don't know what you are trying to achieve, we can't suggest alternatives ... that will work.

Comment: If you are just maintaining a pool of identical connections then you really don't need to iterate through them. In fact they don't really need to be a set. Perfect for your use case would be a `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` which handles the thread safety for you. Use `addFirst` and `pollLast` to manage the pool.

Comment: Question edited- part of the exercise is to have the connection pool as a set. Is there an easier way to do it?